# How to backup Lenovo Password Manager?

Tags: backup, thinkpad, password-management, lenovo-laptop

I just configured some Tasks to backup my Notebook daylie. Now I'd like to include my Lenovo Password Manager. I took a look into the Help but I couldn't find anything besides exporting my data. I automated my backups so it would be a mess to have to export this manually.

So my question is, if there is a file/profile which I can simply backup? If not, is there a way to do this via command-line?

So far, thanks in advice.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the Command Line:

```
"...\Lenovo\Password Manager\pwm_utility.exe" /e filepath="somepath.pwm" password="somepassword"
```